# how to achieve remote desktop using java

Tags: java, desktop, ip

suppose if we need to access a system which is there in any other place then how can we achieve this using java programming.Ip address will be normally used to connect two systems by means of socket,so my questions is like how can we achieve this without using ip address.Please help me out in this.i am searching for the architecture of teamviewer like tool.

Comment: "how can we achieve this without using ip address" - and how do you plan to identify the other system?

Comment: lol do you want the source code @Subash ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to abstract away the IP address of a client to client solution you need *somewhere* to store those IP addresses. So you need a server that holds those keys that maps to an IP address somehow. So your connection would go like this

> client - server - client

Or if the server doesn't want to handle the traffic it could give back an IP to let the clients connect to eachother and exchange data for themselves.

> - client's connects to server
> - client2 asks what ip address client1 has
>
>   - This could be achieved with a key of somekind for instance
> - server sends ip address of client1 to client2
> - client2 tries to connect to the ip address

This only works if one of the clients is reachable from eachother, otherwise you need some third computer to route the data between the clients.